# send url with parameters using ajax

Tags: javascript

I want to send a url with parameters using ajax following is the data I want to sent http://sample-domain.com/send-email.php?pid=3224&act=report but it sends only http://sample-domain.com/send-email.php

Following is my ajax code

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(){

    var x=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
      x[i].addEventListener("click", nextlocation);
    };
  });

  function nextlocation(evt){
     var y = String(this.getAttribute("href"));
     alert(y);
     httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     httpRequest.open('POST', 'setnext.php');
     httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     httpRequest.send('next='+y);
  };



</script>
```

and in setnext.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['next']=$_POST['next'];
```

Comment: Post rest of the code where `nextlocation` invoke

Comment: That requests `setnext.php` not `send-email.php`.

Comment: also `POST` request is not same as `GET`.

Comment: @Quentin setnext is where the ajax sends its request. send-mail.php is part the parameter

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan — It is not part of the URL you have put in the code. Are you implying that `setnext.php` issues an HTTP redirect to `send-email.php`?

Comment: @Quentin I want to send http://sample-domain.com/send-email.php?pid=3224&act=report        to         setnext.php using ajax

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
> ```

You've said that you are encoding the data using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

But here:

```
 httpRequest.send('next='+y);
```

You are just putting an `=` between the key and the value without taking into consideration any of the other rules for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

One of those rules is that `&` separates key=value pairs … and you have a `&` in your data.

You have to encode your data properly.

```
 httpRequest.send('next=' + encodeURIComponent(y));
```

Comment: great bro u understood my question  and thanks for your answer I will try it